# boost::function and multiple argument member-function

Tags: c++, boost-function

I have the following definition of a boost::function object:

```
typedef boost::function<std::string (std::string, std::string)> concat;
```

I am passing this function as a struct constructor argument:

```
struct add_node_value_visitor : boost::static_visitor<>
{
    typedef boost::function<std::string (std::string, std::string)> concat;
    add_node_value_visitor(concat _func, std::string key) : _func_concat(_func), _key(key) {}

    template <typename T>
    void operator() ( const T& value) const
    {
        std::string result = _func_concat(boost::lexical_cast<std::string, T>(value), _key);
    }

    std::string _key;
    concat _func_concat;
};
```

Now I need to pass the `struct add_node_value_visitor` to the following function, however the `boost::function<T>` does not accept the 2 arg member function, in the documentation it says I should use boost::bind, but I am however not sure how I'd do that, seeing I also have to satisfy my boost::apply_visitor function.

```
boost::apply_visitor( add_node_value_visitor( &Decomposer::ConcatValues, key), var); // ConcatValues takes 2 args, var = boost::variant


std::string ConcatValues(std::string str, std::string key);
```

Any ideas anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply an instance of a Decomposer object, like this:

`boost::apply_visitor( add_node_value_visitor( boost::bind( &Decomposer::ConcatValues, yourDecomposer, _1, _2 ), key), var);`

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to be precise without seeing ConcatValue's declaration, but you want something like:

```
boost::bind(&Decomposer::ConcatValues, some_decomposer_instance, _1, _2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what `ConcatValues` really is. I'm guessing that it is actually a non-static member function of a `Decomposer` class, and that as such it doesn't actually expect two but **three** parameters : two strings and the `Decomposer` instance on which it is invoked (`this`).

Boost.Bind is indeed a solution as it will help you *bind* the first argument of the member function to a `Decomposer` instance, and forward the two `std::string` passed :

```
Decomposer decomposer;
boost::apply_visitor(
   add_node_value_visitor(boost::bind(&Decomposer::ConcatValues, &decomposer, _1, _2), var
);
```